How To See available Servers in client using Python and socket module
How can I leverage Python's versatile socket module to enumerate servers on the local network without initiating connections? My aim is to retrieve a list of servers from the client without the need for direct connections.
(Simply İ want To find an available server and get its ip on the same wifi network.)

What do you call list of servers? A list of machines running a specific software or using a specific protocol? Does this list already exists in one master server (Microsoft domain server, DHCP or ARP service, DNS service, etc.)?

import os
devices = []
for device in os.popen('arp -a'): devices.append(device)

OR
import socket
devices2 = [ip for ip in socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname())[2]]


no like i want to find an servers ip and list it like
192.168.0.20 is on
